# Prefer shrinking over growing in a flex container with flex-flow: row wrap

Tags: css, flexbox, image-gallery

Displaying an image gallery of different sized images and ratio with the following specs:

1. No blanks (margins) between images.
2. Respecting the original ratio as much as possible.
3. Images surrounded by a link.
4. Non-JS solution.
5. Images could be cropped a bit.
6. Portable solution.
7. Set of images displayed is random.
8. Images must be displayed from left to right (prevents using columns).

I achieved that with the following flexbox solution:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
section a {
  flex: auto;
}
section img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Controlling flex growability</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/195" width="400" height="195" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/256/400" width="256" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/237" width="400" height="237" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/111" width="400" height="111" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/245" width="400" height="245" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/250/400" width="250" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/269" width="400" height="269" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/288/400" width="288" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/234/400" width="234" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/194/400" width="194" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/222/400" width="222" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/192/400" width="192" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/141" width="400" height="141" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/289" width="400" height="289" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/210/400" width="210" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/187" width="400" height="187" alt="Kitty"></a>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

The solution works, but depending on the size of the window, some pictures are enlarged way too much, I would prefer more elements per row, even if the items needs to be shrinked more.

This means that instead of:
[image: Current solution]

I would prefer a higher density of items so that images never gets enlarged:
[image: Example of expected layout]

I looked for solutions to increase globally the number of elements per row so that images does not get enlarged (or at least not too much: for example: 10% max).

The two *hackish* solutions I have found so far are:

### Solution 1

Using the *zoom* property:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  zoom: 50%;
}
section a {
  flex: auto;
}
section img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Controlling flex growability</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/195" width="400" height="195" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/256/400" width="256" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/237" width="400" height="237" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/111" width="400" height="111" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/245" width="400" height="245" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/250/400" width="250" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/269" width="400" height="269" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/288/400" width="288" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/234/400" width="234" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/194/400" width="194" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/222/400" width="222" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/192/400" width="192" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/141" width="400" height="141" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/289" width="400" height="289" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/210/400" width="210" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/187" width="400" height="187" alt="Kitty"></a>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

But that property works great in Chrome, not in Firefox.

### Solution 2

Emulating the *zoom* property with *width*/*height* and *transform: scale*:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200% !important;
  height: 200% !important;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  float: left;
  margin-right: -100000px;
  margin-bottom: -100000px;
}
section a {
  flex: auto;
}
section img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Controlling flex growability</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/195" width="400" height="195" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/256/400" width="256" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/237" width="400" height="237" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/111" width="400" height="111" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/245" width="400" height="245" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/250/400" width="250" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/269" width="400" height="269" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/288/400" width="288" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/234/400" width="234" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/194/400" width="194" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/222/400" width="222" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/192/400" width="192" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/141" width="400" height="141" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/289" width="400" height="289" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/210/400" width="210" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/187" width="400" height="187" alt="Kitty"></a>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

That solution worked so far, but requires a few hacks, and is far from being elegant and now  will have impacts with the other elements of the page.

Is there any other solution, more flexgrid-oriented that permits that kind of control?
I have tried using *flex-grow: 0*: it, indeed, disables growing items, but then there are blanks around images everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify your starting attempt.

**Main idea** is to change `img` `width: 100%;` to `width: auto;` and specify links' `height`. This will give us images with gaps.

To remove the gaps we could add to links `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;`. Almost done.

**Last step** is to add to links `max-width: 100%;`, it will protect from ovelflow if image `width` will be wider than column in small screen. <strike>Such problem we could see in Temani Afif's first solution with 4th image, if we put higher `height` of links.</strike> Edited

Look into snippet.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

section a {
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 166px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

section img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Controlling flex growability</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/195" width="400" height="195" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/256/400" width="256" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/237" width="400" height="237" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/111" width="400" height="111" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/245" width="400" height="245" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/250/400" width="250" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/269" width="400" height="269" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/288/400" width="288" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/234/400" width="234" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/194/400" width="194" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/222/400" width="222" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/192/400" width="192" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/141" width="400" height="141" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/289" width="400" height="289" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/210/400" width="210" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/187" width="400" height="187" alt="Kitty"></a>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far. It doesn't give the same result than using `zoom` as it fixes all rows to have the exact same height, by doing so: it prevents the natural flex algorithm to "adapt" to something "as optimal as possible".

As far as I understand, it's not yet possible to achieve what I want in a compatible and non hacky way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea where you can consider height to control the size of the rows and the main trick is to rely on `min-width:100%` for your images in order to fill the space.

Basically, the `a` will define the height, the image will follow that height and will compute an `auto` width to keep the ratio. The width of the image will define the width of the link and then the link will grow to fill the space (creating space inside it). Finally, the `min-width:100%` you will make the image fill the space created inside the link.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

section a {
  flex: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

section img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto; /* we need auto to keep the ratio based on the height */
  min-width: 100%; /* we expand the image to fill the gaps */
  max-width:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/195" width="400" height="195" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/256/400" width="256" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/237" width="400" height="237" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/111" width="400" height="111" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/245" width="400" height="245" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/250/400" width="250" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/269" width="400" height="269" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/288/400" width="288" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/234/400" width="234" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/194/400" width="194" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/222/400" width="222" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/192/400" width="192" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/141" width="400" height="141" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/289" width="400" height="289" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/210/400" width="210" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/187" width="400" height="187" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/288/400" width="288" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/234/400" width="234" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/194/400" width="194" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/222/400" width="222" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/192/400" width="192" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/141" width="400" height="141" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/289" width="400" height="289" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/210/400" width="210" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/187" width="400" height="187" alt="Kitty"></a>
</section>
```

If you consider `vw` unit for the height you will have a static grid that will scale while keeping the same overal structure:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

section a {
  flex: auto;
  height: 8vw;
}

section img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;  
  max-width:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/195" width="400" height="195" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/256/400" width="256" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/237" width="400" height="237" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/111" width="400" height="111" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/245" width="400" height="245" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/250/400" width="250" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/269" width="400" height="269" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/288/400" width="288" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/234/400" width="234" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/194/400" width="194" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/222/400" width="222" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/192/400" width="192" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/141" width="400" height="141" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/289" width="400" height="289" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/210/400" width="210" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/187" width="400" height="187" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/288/400" width="288" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/234/400" width="234" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/194/400" width="194" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/222/400" width="222" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/192/400" width="192" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/141" width="400" height="141" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/289" width="400" height="289" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/210/400" width="210" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/187" width="400" height="187" alt="Kitty"></a>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

one way you can solve it is by adding `line-height: 0` to the `a` and setting the `height` value with `px` value.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
section a {
  flex: auto;
  line-height: 0;
}
section img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Controlling flex growability</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/195" width="400" height="195" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/256/400" width="256" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/237" width="400" height="237" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/111" width="400" height="111" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/245" width="400" height="245" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/250/400" width="250" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/269" width="400" height="269" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/288/400" width="288" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/234/400" width="234" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/194/400" width="194" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/222/400" width="222" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/227" width="400" height="227" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/192/400" width="192" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/141" width="400" height="141" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/289" width="400" height="289" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/255" width="400" height="255" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/210/400" width="210" height="400" alt="Kitty"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/187" width="400" height="187" alt="Kitty"></a>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This changes the height of every rows, it doesn't permit more items per row as with the zoom effect or the equivalent hack.