# CSS Grid different amount of items per row

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

Im trying to recreate the following distribution on a CSS grid, but im not getting there.

[image]

I've tried the following:

```
display: inline-grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto;
```

But the columns get the biggest element width in all the grid.

What im trying to do is fill the row with the most amount of elements as i can respecting the element aspect ratio and with a max height for each row.

I dont know if this is possible using a CSS grid or should i use other CSS layout?

I made a JS script that does this but im trying to make the same behaviour with CSS for better performance and less bugs.

EDIT
Heights might be different for each row to adjust the ratios and prevent images croping.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: it's not possible with CSS grid

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60216458/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, that is almost what i need. I will try with that and changing something to not allow images to crop.