# How to make flex layout fill width 100% using image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8VDg.jpg)

I want to collocate my photos using  flex layout, but there are spaces left like a photo.

[I want this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBZbI.jpg)

This is the result I want. How can I make it the same?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60216458/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif
WoW.... Thank Bro!!!